# Convertion of Elasticsearch Query from 2.0 to 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch

Guys I am newbie in elastic search and trying to migrate from 2.* to 5.*.

I have a query which I cannot convert. I tried searching google, as well as read documentation but examples in it are very basic and don't really help in here. Maybe someone can help me to convert the following query into modern one? I am using php client for it.

```
$query = [
    'index' => 'index_name',
    'type'  => 'table',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query'  => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            [
                                'match' => [
                                    '_all' => [
                                        'query'     => 'zonda',
                                        'fuzziness' => 1,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    [
                        'term' => [
                            'foo' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'size'  => 10000,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much into php, so could not check it, but it should be something like this:

```
$query = [
    'index' => 'index_name',
    'type'  => 'table',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            '_all' => [
                                'query'     => 'zonda',
                                'fuzziness' => 1,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    [
                        'term' => [
                            'foo' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'size'  => 10000,
];
```

The filtered query is now gone, and you can use the filter part of the bool query.

Comment: says bool query can't have query parameter.

Comment: Bool query has option for must / must_not / should / filter, in there you can put the query. You do not need the additional query in the bool that you have given in your question